# Iterating through a list to find object are equal

Tags: java, sql, oracle, collections, java-8

I have a result set as below which I get returned using Left join and other conditions.

```
ID1 - table1 (unique)
ID2 - table2 (unique)
type - table2 
AMt3 - table2
```

my final result set is as:

```
ID1       ID2   Type    AMT

1835748   21987   9     4

1835748   12898   26    5

1835748   21986   26    5

2242186   21421   1    11

2242186   21422   1    20

2242186   21988   1    30
```

now I have look through this data and sum up the amount where type and ID1 are same.

In the above example
row1 - remains as in 
row 2+3 - sum are added and returned
row 4+5+6 - sum is returned

so finally I will have only 3 records which I need to sent to another system.

Is it possible to achieve this using query? I have given simple representation as of now , query is more complex.

or if this can be done I java code? 
How Do I achieve this?

Comment: You would have to either lose ID2 from the final result set, or pick one of the available values (e.g. either 12898 or 21986 for the second combination) based on some criteria you haven't mentioned. If you don't want any ID2 then you might want to modify your original query to not include it in the first place, if it's already doing aggregation. Without seeing what that query is doing now, though, it's hard to say what you need to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that already in SQL. Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`.

```
SELECT T1.ID1,
       T2.TYPE,
       MAX(T2.ID2) ID2,
       SUM(T2.AMT) AMT
       FROM <your join>
       GROUP BY T1.ID1,
                T2.TYPE;
```

Replace `<your join>` with your join operation. And possibly change `MAX()` to `MIN()`, if you like the least `ID2`, rather than the greatest. Or leave that out all together.

Comment: The `MAX(T2.ID2)` is required because ID2 is not used in the aggregation logic, and we can't include columns which don't participate in the aggregation in the projection. Using `max()` is a crude solution but the only better solution is to exclude T2.ID2 from the projection altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Max! It works!

You can do that already in SQL. Use GROUP BY and MAX().

SELECT T1.ID1,
       T2.TYPE,
       MAX(T2.ID2) ID2,
       SUM(T2.AMT) AMT
       FROM 
       GROUP BY T1.ID1,
                T2.TYPE;
Replace  with your join operation. And possibly change MAX() to MIN(), if you like the least ID2, rather than the greatest. Or leave that out all together.